# Running a Particular Function after a duration of 2 hours of occurance of an event in Django

Tags: django, multithreading, celery

Currently i am working on a Django project .Use case is when i add a device object in database,if it does not come online in the first 2 hours after addition then i need to delete that device object from database .

i have written a function **delete_device_from_db()** which delete device if it not comes online.How to invoke this function exactly after 2 hours after the addition of device.

In our project we are using celery to run background tasks and periodic tasks.
what is the best way to solve this.can it be solved using celery?

Comment: You could use **signals.py** with a **post_save** method, so when a new device is saved in your DB you can launch a **celery** function with, for example, a **time.sleep(7200)** and then calling **delete_device_from_db()**. There is probably a better way.

Comment: is it a good idea to use  sleep  function in celery task ? will celery worker execute other functions assigned to it ,if it encounters sleep in one of the executing function?

Comment: @mahender Better not use sleep inside the task. You can create a One time periodic task entry in Celery that runs after 2 hours.

Comment: maby rocetry help [link]https://github.com/Miksus/rocketry   but i didn't check it out yet just seen it in pycoders weekly

Answer (score 0):

Don't run a celery task just to keep it paused for 2 hours. That's not a good approach. It will keep your celery worker occupied. What happens if you have a few devices going offline? It'll totally jam your application.

What i recommend you to do is to have a celery beat task that runs every 5 minutes, and runs a check of the last updated datetime of each device.

```
from django.utils import timezone

if (timezone.now() - device.updated) > datetime.timedelta(hours=2):
    device.delete_device_from_db()
```

P.S. I'm assuming here that your device model has a `updated` field. If not, add it.

```
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```